# Cloudflare nginx server nodejs app SSL error

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ssl, cloudflare

I have a config at /etc/nginx/sites-avaible. My project working on 3010 port. I redirect my domain dns to cloudflare, activate to SSL. But i can not reach the https://domain.xyz.
I'm kinda newbie on devops.

```
upstream zapbot.xyz {
    server 127.0.0.1:3010;
    keepalive 8;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name zapbot.xyz www.zapbot.xyz;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/zapbot.xyz.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

      proxy_pass http://zapbot.xyz/;
      proxy_redirect off;
    }

 }
```

Comment: On cloudflare did you use the "ssl > full" option? You might need to add listening on port 443 as well. You can test that by changing from "full" to "flexible" on clouldflare, which will let cloudflare talk to your site on port 80, which you have in your nginx.

Comment: Hi Cargrison, can you confirm if this has solved your issue? If yes @sur.la.route please put this as your answer so this question can be marked answered and closed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On cloudflare did you use the "ssl > full" option? You might need to add listening on port 443 as well. You can test that by changing from "full" to "flexible" on clouldflare, which will let cloudflare talk to your site on port 80, which you have in your nginx.